# fileInput box with label next to Button

Tags: r, shiny

In a shiny-app I want to put a `fileInput()`-Box next to an `actionButton()`. However I can't align the boxes properly next to each other because the label of the `fileInput()`-Box moves the box down.

[image]

I can't remove the label of the `fileInput()`-Box, nor give the `actionButton()` a label 'above the box' (which wouldn't be nice anyway).

How can I move the `actionButton()` down to be in line with the `fileInput()`-Box?

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      splitLayout(
        fileInput('file', 'put in file'),
        actionButton('action', 'click here')
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      'Test'
    )
  )
)

server = function(input,output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the position with the css attribute `margin-top`:

```
actionButton('action', 'click here', style='margin-top:25px')
```